# Why is stoi causing an error and how to fix in Makefile

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been trying to run a code that uses stoi, below is the makefile, each time I run this code I get an 'error: 'stoi' was not declared in this scope', any idea how I can include the C++11 compiler in the make file

```
#compile and link the application
all: main

#run the application
run: main
./main

#link main.o, time.o, and date.o to excutuable main, with debug messages 
and functions visible
debug: temp.o day.o cal.o
g++ -g -c -Duse_debug main.cpp
g++ -g -o main main.o temp.o day.o cal.o

#link main.o, temp.o, and day.o to executable main
main: main.o temp.o day.o cal.o
g++ -g -o main main.o temp.o day.o cal.o 

#compile the main.cpp to main.o
main.o: main.cpp
g++ -g -c main.cpp

#compile the temp.cpp to temp.o
temp.o: temp.cpp
g++ -g -c temp.cpp

#compile the day.cpp to day.o
day.o: day.cpp
g++ -g -c day.cpp

#compile the cal.cpp to cal.o
cal.o: cal.cpp
g++ -g -c cal.cpp

#remove built files
clean:
rm -rf main main.o temp.o day.o cal.o *~
```

Here's a sample code of the part the uses stoi,

```
#include <iostream>    //cin and cout
#include <string>    //stoi(), getline()
#include <cctype>    //isdigit()
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int input;
string inputS;
cin>> inputS;
input = stoi(inputS);    //converts inputStr to int type
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem may be the C++11 complier, I just need to know how I could fix that in the makefile

Comment: Please post your code itself, or better yet a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It could well be you not using the `std::` prefix and we can't tell just by looking at your Makefile. Or post the version of g++ you're using--it may well be that its default version is pre-c++11 and you need to add `-std=c++11` (or later) to the Makefile.

Comment: where can I add -std=c+11 in the makefile because the g++ I'm using is pre-c++11

Comment: Someone please help, thanks!

Comment: Never mind i got it!